# Desktop Streaming Error(Raspberry pi Live Desktop & Audio Streaming to the browser with WebRTC)

Tags: pi-2, streaming-video, webrtc

I wanted to load the xscreen driver. so I opened a terminal and typed the following commands:

```
$uv4l --driver xscreen --auto-video_nr --display :0 --framerate 10 --server-option '--port=5678'
```

This is the normal result:

```
raspberrypi ~ $ uv4l --driver xscreen --auto-video_nr --display :0 --framerate 10 --server-option '--port=5678'
[core] Trying driver 'xscreen' from built-in drivers...
[core] Driver 'xscreen' not found
[core] Trying driver 'xscreen' from external plug-in's...
[driver] Opening display: :0
[driver] Display open, screen 0: 640x480, depth: 24, bpp: 32, big endian: false
[driver] Specified capturing rectangle: (xorigin 0, yorigin 0, width 640, height 480)
[core] Device detected!
[core] Trying to load the the Streaming Server plug-in...
[server] HTTP Streaming & WebRTC Signalling Server v1.1.18 built on Apr 22 2015
[core] Streaming Server loaded!
[core] Cannot create /dev/video0 because file already exists
[core] Registering device node /dev/video1
[server] Web Streaming Server listening on port 9000
```

But my result do not have this part:

```
[server] HTTP Streaming & WebRTC Signalling Server v1.1.18 built on Apr 22 2015
[core] Streaming Server loaded!
```

What is the problem? Help me please!

Comment: Any reason why you are not using the UV4L raspidisp driver instead? The raspidiso driver is similar to the xscreen driver that you are using, but does not necessarily require an X server to run and is also accelarated

Answer (score 0):

Either ignore the fact that that part is missing from the output or run uv4l with the -f switch. Just make sure that the server is listening to the port specified in the command line.